# Python closing process, thread, pipe, queue, timers

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, pyqt5

I have a couple processes and threads that communicate with pipes and queues. I need to close it all but a get error

> Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

I think the problem is in the order of closing. First i try to close processes then threads and then queues and pipes

```
def reset(self):
    try:
        self.process.terminate()
        self.processBullet.terminate()
        self.tankCollisionProcess.terminate()
        self.processEWC.terminate()
        self.processECB.terminate()
        self.thread.stop()
        self.thread_enemy_bullet.stop()
        if self.move_to_new_level is False:
            self.thread_enemy_move.stop()
            self.myPipe1.close()
            self.myPipe2.close()
            self.queueTile.close()
            self.myPipe1 = None
            self.myPipe2 = None
            self.queueTile = None

        self.queueTileC.close()
        self.queueEWC.close()
        self.pipeB1.close()
        self.pipeB2.close()
        self.pipeBullet1.close()
        self.pipeBullet2.close()
        self.pipeT1.close()
        self.pipeT2.close()
        self.pipe1.close()
        self.pipe2.close()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        self.process = None
        self.processBullet = None
        self.tankCollisionProcess = None
        self.processECB = None
        self.processEWC = None
        self.thread = None
        self.thread_enemy_bullet = None

        self.player.hide()
        self.player.destroy()
        self.player = None
        self.level.remove_map()
        self.level = None

        self.timer_pecurkica.disconnect()
        self.timer_pecurkica.stop()
        self.timer_pecurkica_hide.disconnect()
        self.timer_pecurkica_hide.stop()
        self.timer_dexm.disconnect()
        self.timer_dexm.stop()
        self.no_pu.disconnect()
        self.no_pu.stop()
        self.power_up = None
        self.enemies.delete_all_enemies()
        self.enemies = None
```

Comment: "Python finished with exit code" is not an error afaik. It simply suggests that the program has completed running and exited.

Comment: Are you expecting the program to do anymore after the "reset" method that it is not doing currently? If yes, please share the upstream and downstream code-snippets.